# Selenium Disable Edge PDF Viewer in new tab

Tags: selenium, selenium-edgedriver

I want to disable PDF opening in new tab and instead download the PDF while executing the selenium scripts on Edge browser.

For Chrome, I have the below chrome options and it works fine.

```
 chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.plugins_disabled", new[] { "Chrome PDF Viewer" });
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
```

On Edge, I tried below but it does not work.

```
edgeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
edgeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
```

Am I missing some steps?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it is working:

```
Map<String, Object> preferences = new HashMap<String, Object>();
preferences.put("download.default_directory", location);
preferences.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);

EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);

WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

For 'location', set any local path to download pdf file.